# I can not print the response data

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                isLoading: true,
        search:'',
            };
              }

  componentDidMount(){
    var url = 'url=';
      axios.get(url)
      .then(response =>this.onResponse(response.data));
  }

  onResponse(rdata){
    this.setState({
      isLoading:false,
      veri:rdata.data
    });
  }


  searchData(search) {
    this.setState({search});
    var url = 'url='+search;
    axios.get(url).then(response => this.onResponse(response.data));
}


control(){
  if(this.state.search.length>3)
  {
      this.state.veri.map((userData) => {
        <Text>{userData.title}</Text>
    });
  }
}


  render()
  {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          onChangeText = {(search) => this.searchData(search)}
          placeholder="Welcome">
        </TextInput>
         {this.control()}
        </View>
    );
  }
```

my data is {[{}{}{}{}{}{}{}...]}. print to console.log but in render, I can not print in text . How do I print this in text in render ? under the textinput print to {this.control()} it did not work , print to between text but it did not work please help me :(

Comment: Update your code and put where you are calling `this.control()`

Comment: ım update to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so two `return` are missing  :

```
control(){
  if(this.state.search.length>3)
  {
     return  this.state.veri.map((userData) => { 
        return <Text>{userData.title}</Text> 
    });
  }
  return null;
}
```

Indeed, when you forgot `return` , `this.control()` returns `undefined`.. Also consider:

- to use `key` props  with `<Text />`as you are rendering an array .
- to use only one return since the second return can be removed when you remove `{}`

So below, the more elegant solution :

```
    control() {

       if(this.state.search.length <= 3) return null; // mitigate the number of return by reverse the condition and return directly.
       return  this.state.veri.map((({title})) => <Text key={title}>{title}</Text>);

    }
```